# no puedo concluir la instalacion de netbeans en mi mac

Tags: java, netbeans, macos, instalacion

Al momento de querer instalar NetBeans, me pide ciertas cosas a las que yo acepto (lo de siempre). Pero ya en el último paso me aparece que hubo un error durante la instalación, que el paquete "baseide-8.0.1.pkg" no es de confianza.

Por favor, necesito ayuda urgente, ya que tengo que empezar a programar en Java para un proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si confías en que el instalador es seguro y confiable, necesitas cambiar la configuración de seguridad:

- Abre "Preferencias del sistema"
- Pulsa "Seguridad y privacidad"
- Pulsa la pestaña "General"
- Haz clic en el bloqueo e ingresa tu contraseña de administrador
- En "Permitir aplicaciones desde cualquier lugar" marque el botón de opción "En cualquier lugar"
- Luego haga clic en el botón "Permitir desde cualquier lugar"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]